# Unable to load OpenVas on Virtual Box on Windows 10

Tags: virtualbox, iso-image

I watched this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a6okiWbcUco

Follow though, when I click start I kept getting

[image]

[image]

I tried to select my iso already ?

Am I selecting it wrong ?

Comment: Did you install Kali Linux first so that you could install OpenVas in Kali?

Comment: Kali ? What you mean, ? This is on my Windows 10 machine.

Comment: Is your Windows 10 machine the Host or is it a virtual machine?  Whichever , it does not run natively in Windows 10. You need to run it in a Linux System.  https://www.peerlyst.com/posts/openvas-network-vulnerability-scanning-for-beginners-step-one-installation-kimberly-crawley

Comment: It is taking a while but OpenVas is installing here on a linux guest machine (Kali)

Comment: This is the appliance version. You can load it on Virtual box. See YouTube video, I shared.

Comment: I did review the video and I cannot see what is wrong.

Comment: Me too, but he didn't show how he selected the *iso*, he just drag the windows up, boom, and start the instance.